Window is not defined with Angular SSR and coreui
I'm currently trying to add a carousel to my angular 17 app with SSR.
The carousel I'm trying to add is the first one of this page :
https://coreui.io/angular/docs/components/carousel
I'm new to Angular, I saw that with SSR, we can't use the window object. But the error is coming from core-ui because without using the core-ui template, my app works well.
I'm adding the error in the attached file.
Thank you for your help! I tried something but I'm not good enough for this sadly

The carousel form the document should have been successfully displayed, but I had the window error instead

Edit: I found a way to solve this.
I'm rendering the carousel part only if this is played by a navigator
On component.typescript file :
isBrowser: boolean;

constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: object) {
    this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId);
}

On component.html :
@if (isBrowser) {
   code...
}

